# Swing - calling events from inside panel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener

I have simple Swing GUI with main window `JFrame` and its main panel derive from `JPanel`. The panel has some buttons that can be clicked and generate events.

I want these events affect data stored in `JFrame` because it is my main application - it has some queues for thread, open streams and so on.

So how do I make my button in panel invoke callbacks in its parent frame? What is best practice of this for Java/Swing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To invoke methods in the parent frame you need a reference to the parent frame. So your JPanel's constructor can be declared like this:

```
 public MyPanel(MyFrame frame){
    super();
    this.frame = frame;
    //the rest of your code
}
```

And in the JFrame you invoke this constructor like this:

```
  panel = new MyPanel(this);//this refers to your JFrame
```

In the event handlers attached to your buttons you now have access to the frame and can invoke the various methods as needed.

```
  button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
           //do some stuff
           frame.someMethod();//invoke method on frame
           //do more stuff
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use addActionListener method on desired buttons specifying the class implementing ActionListener.

```
ActionListenerClass actionListenerObject = new actionListenerClass();
JButton b = new JButton("Button");
b.addActionListener(actionListenerObject);

public class ActionListenerClass implements ActionListener(){
 //or better : actionListenerClass extends AbstractAction
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      }
}
```

EDIT:

> Yes, I know this. But the action
>   listener I want to be in parent JFrame
>   class - this is the problem

then extends JFrame class making the new derived class implementing the desired interface.

Comment: Yes, I know this. But the action listener I want to be in parent JFrame class - *this is the problem*

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) tutorial for using SwingWorker.

Comment: why it help me? I just want clean way access JFrame from JPanel it contains

Comment: sry, it was unclear. you can use `SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor( JPanel )` for getting the parent window

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the `ActionListener` in your class that has the JFrame (or extends it):

```
class MyPanelClass {
    public MyPanelClass(ActionListener al)
    {
        //...
        JButton myButton = new JButton("Button");
        myButton.addActionListener(al);
        //...
    }
}
```

---

```
class MainClass extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    public void someMethod() {
        MyPanelClass mpc = new MyPanelClass(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        // your implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: But then, have to demultiplex all buttons have called into it, right? all reach same `actionPerformed` callback?

Comment: That's correct. And I see the problem you are talking about. Maybe passing the frame is a better option...